# MultiSystem on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've been trying to install the **MultiSystem** script on my **Ubuntu 14.04 x64** machine and i am in trouble since it does not find my pendrives due their mount points: all the removable media is mounted under **/media/*username*** in this distro and it seems the script is looking for memory sticks under **/media** simply.

I tried three instalation methods: 
1) adding the packages **gtkdialog_0.8.3-1_amd64.deb** and **multisystem_1.0293_all.deb** with **dpkg**;
2) using the **install-depot-multisystem.sh** script, downloaded from [here](http://liveusb.info/multisystem/install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2);
3) using the method described on this [tutorial](http:///www.unixmen.com/create-multiboot-usb-ubuntu-using-multisystem/). None of these worked fine.

Did anybody have the same problem and could fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

To install multisystem

> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot all main'
>
> wget -q http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot/multisystem.asc -O- |sudo apt-key add -
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install multisystem

If multisystem doesn't find USB is becouse the USB format isn't FAT32

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. For some reason, after a reboot, everything is set. Unfortunately, I am not sure about which approach was the good one. :/